# Serialization of a class which doesnt implement Serializable

Tags: java, serializable

I have 2 classes serial1 and serial 2. serial1 implements Serializable whereas serial2 does not.As per theory i should get an Exception for the following code, but it is working  fine. why is it so ?

```
import java.io.*;

public class SerialTest {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        FileOutputStream fos=null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos =null;
        serial1 se = new serial1();
        serial1 sd = null;
        se.mets();
        try {
             fos= new FileOutputStream("serialtest");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            oos =new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            oos.writeObject(se);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileInputStream fis=null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("serialtest");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            sd = (serial1) ois.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sd.mets();

    }

}


import java.io.Serializable;

public class serial1 implements Serializable{

    /* public static void main(String []args){      
         serial1 ss = new serial1();
         ss.mets();
     }*/

     public void mets(){
         serial2 s2  = new serial2();
         System.out.println( "serial 1 + mets");
         s2.met1();
     }
}


public class serial2 {

    public void met1(){
        System.out.println("serial2  + met1");
    }

}
```

---------------------------*
The output is

serial 1 + mets

serial2  + met1

serial 1 + mets

serial2  + met1

Comment: Where/why do you think you should have an exception?

Comment: As a side note: You probably don't need to separate everything into it's own try/catch block. If creating `fos` throws a `FileNotFoundException`, do you *really* still want to try to make `oos`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually serialize `serial2`. Your `mets` method creates a local variable but as soon as the method returns it goes out of scope and becomes eligible for garbage collection.

If you had an instance variable of type `serial2` inside `serial1` then you would see an exception when you try to serialize (assuming it's a non-null value), but a local variable will not be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see you ever serializing `serial2`